# Defining which method can be chained

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, chaining

I created a class that supports chaining by making use of `return this;`, and
now I need to make the current method tell what methods can be chained. Example:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(path) {
    this.path = path;
  }

  method1() {
    // some code here...
    // i must make something here to only allow channing if it's method
    // blabliblu
    return this;
  }

  blabliblu() {
    // some code here...
    // same thing here, if the channing is with the method ar_2, it's ok.
    return this;
  }

  ar_2() {
    // And so on...
    return this;
  }
}
```

So, i can do: `method1().blabliblu()`, but i can't do `method1().ar_2()`. Is there lib to help me achieve this?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for help with.  The normal way to let someone know what methods support chaining is with documentation for your object.  You could, of course, code your own method that returned a list of methods that support chaining, but I'm not sure why that would be useful.  The person calling the code needs to know when they are writing their code (not at run-time) how a given method they plan to use works.

Comment: FYI, in your code example both `obj.method1().blabliblu()` and `obj.method1().ar_2()` could work just fine because `obj.method1()` returns the original object so any method on that object can be successfully chained to `obj.method1()`.

Comment: I think what she wants to do is be able to restrict which methods can chain to other methods.  For example, method1().blabliblu() is allowed but method1().ar_2() is not allowed.  Also, ar_2().blabliblu() is allowed but ar_2().method1() is now allowed.

Comment: Yes, that's it! @SohrabHejazi

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?  There's nothing magic about chaining when your methods return `this`.  It's just another way to call a publicly defined method.  So, why would you want to define a public method and allow it to be called with `obj.b()`, but not as `obj.a().b()`.  One could always just do `obj.a()` and then `obj.b()` and execute the exact same code as `obj.a().b()`.  So, preventing chaining of a public method does not prevent anything.   What/why are you really trying to accomplish?  Give up on the abstract description and tell us the real problem to solve.

Comment: @SohrabHejazi - That makes no sense.  In Javascript a publicly defined method can be called on any instance of the object.  It does not matter whether the instance is obtained via the return value of a previously chained method or the instance is stored in a variable and referenced from there.  To Javascript, there is no difference.  So, as long as all the methods are returning the same object, the generic description for what the OP is asking for cannot be done and has no use because it wouldn't be preventing anything.

Comment: Now, if you aren't returning the SAME object (as your example shows), but a different object from your methods, then you can control which methods can be called on the returned object by returning a different object that only has some methods.  That is chaining where each function returns a different object as in `[1,2,3].map(...).filter(...)` where each step in that chain returns a different object.  If you actually change the type of the object returned, then subsequent objects in the chain could have different methods.  But, you can't do that with `return this` the way you show.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree.  I don't think it is doable in Javascript.  I was just trying to clarify what she was asking for as there seemed to be some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have asked for is not possible in Javascript.  When you do:

```
return this;
```

in your methods, you are returning the same object.  Any public method can be called on the object that is returned and there is no way to specify that because the object was returned from a method it should somehow not allow some methods to be called.

So, using the code in your example where you `return this` in `.method1()`, there's no difference between this:

```
obj.method1();
obj.ar_2();
```

and this:

```
obj.method1().ar_2();
```

That's because the chained version is essentially this internal to the JS interpreter:

```
let temp = obj.method1();
temp.ar_2();
```

So, if `temp` is the same as `obj` which it is when you `return this` from `method1()`, then `obj.method1().ar_2();` is just the same as `obj.method1(); obj.ar_2();` (with a little less typing).  Thus, you can't prevent the calling of `.ar_2()`.

Both just call `.method1()` and then `.ar_2()` on the same object.  So you can't prevent one scheme, but allow the other.  `ar_2` is either a public method or it isn't.  You can't have it callable in one place and not callable in another on the same object.

---

Now, you could make `obj.method1()` return a different object.  If you did that, then that different object could have different methods on it and could be an object that does not have a `.ar_2()` method.

When you chain array methods like this:

```
let result = [1,2,3].map(...).filter(...);
```

Each step in that chain is returning a different object (they are not doing a `return this`, but are creating a new object and returning it.  In this specific Array example, these are returning different objects, but of the same type, but you could return different objects of different types.  For example:

```
let result = ["a","b","c"].join("").toUpperCase();
```

Here, `.join()` is an Array method, but returns a string object which you can then only call string methods on.  So, you could do something like that where you return a different type of object.